# Change <td> background color in PHP using CSS

Tags: php, html, css

I have the following PHP code that fill table from mySQL database

```
<?php               
     while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>".$res['id']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$res['name']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$res['number']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$res['nid']."</td>";     
 }
 ?>
```

Using CSS, How can I change background color for **nid** field?

I'm has trying the below, but it doesn't work:

```
echo "<td style="background-color:red" >".$res['nid']."</td>";
```

Comment: Use `'background-color:red'` instead

Comment: Or simply escape the double quotes i.e. `echo "<td style=\"background-color:red\" >".$res['nid']."</td>";

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
echo "<td style='background-color:red' >".$res['nid']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
echo "<td style='background-color:red'>".$res['nid']."</td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of the following examples.

Use different "quotes" for attributes

```
echo '<td style="background-color:red">'.$res['nid'].'</td>';
```

Or use the [Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

```
echo "<td style='background-color:red'>{$res['nid']}</td>";
```

Or you can escape the double quotes in the string

```
echo "<td style=\"background-color:red\">".$res['nid']."</td>";
```

Or use multiple techniques

```
echo "<td style=\"background-color:red\">{$res['nid']}</td>";
```

Do note that the `{}` can only be used in a `string`/ double quotes.

Your code doesn't work since everytime you use the same quote after the first you break out of the string. So with:

```
"<td style="background-color:red" >".$res['nid']."</td>";
```

PHP thinks `"<td style="` is a string and `background-color:red` is PHP code which it isn't. You can see that in the code highlighting aswell. Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php) will help you explain it a bit better.

Comment: Funny how everyone is giving a solution, but doesn't explain why it's not working. If you explain not to or how to mix quotes, I'll upvote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the " character. The escaping character is \, so you have to use it as a prefix for your ". For example:

```
<?php               
     $val1="I want this normal";
     $val2="I want this normal";
     $val3="I want this normal";
     $val4="I want this RED";

     echo "<table><tr>";
     echo "<td>".$val1."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$val2."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$val3."</td>";
     echo "<td style=\"background-color:red;\" >".$val4."</td>"; //Change the " for '  or escape " with \
     echo "</tr></table>";  //And don't forget to close this tag too ;)
```

?>

In your code it would be something like:

```
<?php               
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {         
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$res['id']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$res['name']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$res['number']."</td>";
     echo "<td style=\"background-color:red\" >".$res['nid']."</td>";
```

}
 ?>